# redux Asyncthunk returning value before async function can complete execution

Tags: reactjs, arrays, async-await

I am creating a redux async thunk to connect my application to firebase. I am traversing an array and for each of its elements I need to fetch a document from firebase. But asyncthunk function is returning value even before the loop completes.

```js
export const getBookings = createAsyncThunk('bookings/get', async (user) => {
  // console.log(user)
  let bookingdata = []

  await user.bookings.forEach(async (booking) => {
    // console.log(booking)
    if (booking !== '') {
      const docRef = doc(db, 'bookings', booking)
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef)
      let book = docSnap.data()

      const vehRef = doc(db, 'mumbai', book.vehicleid)
      const vehSnap = await getDoc(vehRef)
      let vehicle = vehSnap.data()
      // console.log(vehicle)
      book = { ...book, ...vehicle }
      console.log(book)
      bookingdata = [...bookingdata, book]
    }
  })
  console.log(bookingdata)
  return bookingdata
})
```

Here, the function fetches a document from firebase, which I am recieving successfully. But return statement gets executed even before for loop can complete and returns an empty list.
[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKCED.png)
What to do?

Comment: `.forEach` does not know anything about promises. It won't wait for them, and it doesn't return one.